SEM with 50% missing data (due to distribution of items over various survey ballots/waves)
I want to test a multilevel mediation (particularly, test a number of hypotheses about possible mediators of the effect of social class on Right-Wing Authoritarianism) using largely categorical variables surveyed in the General Social Survey, and for this, I would have liked to use Structural Equation Modeling.  However, I have doubts about its feasibility, due to missing data.
In fact, there is not a single participant with data on all variables I want to include, because the items were each asked in different waves or ballots. For example, I would have one item that was only asked in ballots A and B, a second item that only occurred in ballots B and C, and a third in ballots A and C. Because I am dealing with categorical data, I am considering WLSMV in Mplus, which uses pairwise deletion. In theory, I can draw up a covariance matrix, since every variable co-occurs with every other variable in one ballot or another. For each pair of variables (so for each covariance I need), I have at least 900 participants (though out of a total of more than 10.000 participants). Therefore, intuitively, using pair-wise deletion does not seem very problematic to me, since most missingness should be MCAR (they result from randomization in the administration of certain ballots/modules) - with perhaps the exception of a few variables that were not asked in particular years/waves. However, when I read about this, it is often recommended that pair-wise deletion is not justified when you have more than 10% missingness (a threshold that I far exceed here).
Is there a method of dealing with missingnes that allows me to estimate this model, even though each respondent has randomly missing data on around 50% of the variables? Or is it not feasible/advisable to use SEM in my case?

Regarding this comment:

Therefore, intuitively, using list-wise deletion does not seem very problematic to me, since most missingness should be MCAR (they result from randomization in the administration of certain ballots/modules) - with perhaps the exception of a few variables that were not asked in particular years/waves.

I don't necessarily agree that this is MCAR. MCAR assumes that there is literally nothing influencing the missingness other than pure randomness (the key being randomness that you have no ability to account for whatsoever). Your scenario sounds more like MAR because you have clearly determined a factor in your data which predicts this: the wave of the testing. From Little et al. (2014, p.2):

The second mechanism, termed missing at random (MAR), refers to missingness that is due to a predictable reason and, therefore, becomes a random effect that is easily estimated.

A key component that is helpful for your problem is noted in your comment here:

In fact, there is not a single participant with data on all variables I want to include, because the items were each asked in different waves or ballots.

While the data is missing for some, it is not missing for all of the participants (if that were the case, it would indeed be silly to include the variable given it cannot vary meaningfully). Because you have data for some, you can predict data for others, where things like multiple imputation, random forest imputation, FIML, etc. are helpful (using variables such as the wave of testing as one of the key indicators for imputation).
I can't imagine a scenario anyway where throwing out a large percentage of your data would be a useful procedure unless there was a strong reason. Mplus has tools for this (I know it uses FIML at least), and I would recommend sticking to those for this problem.
Reference
Little, T. D., Jorgensen, T. D., Lang, K. M., & Moore, E. W. G. (2014). On the joys of missing data. Journal of Pediatric Psychology, 39(2), 151–162. https://doi.org/10.1093/jpepsy/jst048

The OP might benefit from Stef van Buuren's online text, too. (+1)

Thank you very much for your answer!
If i would use multiple imputation, then 50% of my data (for some variables even 80% of the data for that variable) would be imputed. Does this large percentage of imputed data not pose problems?

If anything, deleting half of your data would lead to substantial bias, whereas your imputation would give you plausible predictions of what that data should be. Given the GSS is a well-known survey, I looked up if this has ever been dealt with before, and it seems there is some past literature on imputation on the GSS data: https://www.jstor.org/stable/42956310

Thank you for the source! However, I dont understand why pairwise deletion would be deleting half of my data? (the listwise deletion was a writing mistake, bc then i would have 0 participants left: they all have missings on at least some variables)

Ah sorry pairwise can recover some data in that case, but you still have other issues that crop up, which given we have already established this as MAR makes problematic: https://www.statisticssolutions.com/missing-data-listwise-vs-pairwise/

Ok, thank you very much for the sources! So it is appropriate then to do analyses on a dataset in which half of the cells are imputed data, and containing some variables for which 80% of data is imputed?

Sorry for the delayed reply (been on vacation). Yes MICE can often work with various levels of missingness across the data.
